# Using the chain rule to prove existence of derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have occasionally come across "proofs" of the following kind:

If we have a function $f(x)=g(h(x))$ and we know that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, but we do not know anything about the differentiability of $h$, then using the chain rule $f'(x)=h'(x)g'(h(x))$, so granted $g'(h(x))$ is not zero, $h'(x)=f'(x)/g'(h(x))$, with the conclusion being that $h'(x)$ exists and equals $f'(x)/g'(h(x))$.

I was wondering to what degree such reasoning is valid. That is: I was wondering as long as $g'(h(x))$ is not zero, does $h'(x)$ exist and is equal to what is given above. I have tried to fiddle around with the difference quotients, but I run into the problems with the fact that I cannot say the product of two limits is the limit of the products unless I know all limits in question exist.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: When you write down $h'(x),g'(x)$, or $f'(x)$ you are already assuming all these derivatives exist.  Just as you say though, you need to make sure $g'(h(x))$ is not equal to zero.  I don't see any hidden strings.  I don't think there are any extra stipulations

Comment: I edited slightly. The point is that we do not know that $h'(x)$ exists, but I have seen this manipulation of symbols with the conclusion that "therefore $h'(x)$ exists".

Comment: Basically, the fact that $g'(h(c))$ is not equal to zero allows you use the [Inverse Function Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem). That is, $g$ has an inverse function in a small interval containing $h(c)$. On this small interval, $h(x) = g^{-1}(f(x))$, and the derivative of $h$ would exist.